# Tikz curve node midway in-between curved lines while breaking line

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there are any easy way to insert a node in between a curved line as shown in the figure? Using `node[midway] {$\alpha$}` would just place the text next to the curves.

Also, is it possible to make sure that these lines stay parallel to each other?

[image: nodes between curved lines]

EDIT:
The code I am using is:

```
\def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5)% Syntax: [draw options] (center) (initial angle:final angle:radius)
    { \draw[#1] ($(#2)+({#5*cos(#3)},{#5*sin(#3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5); }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5]
    \coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (B) at (0, .7);
    \coordinate (C) at (2, 0);
    \coordinate (D) at ($0.75*(B)+0.25*(C)$);
    \coordinate (E) at ($0.6*(A)+.4*(B)$);
    \scope[rotate=-19, shift=(D)]\input{figures/clarky}\endscope
    \draw[thick] (B) -- (C);
    \draw[thick] (A) -- (C);
    \draw[dashed] (E) -- (C);
    \centerarc[thick, <->, ](C)(179.5:161:2) node[loc=.5, fill=white] {$\alpha$};
    \centerarc[thick, <->, ](C)(179.5:172.5:1.8);
    \centerarc[thick, <->, ](C)(171.5:161:1.8);
    \begin{scope}[shift={(-.5, 0)}, scale=.17]
        \draw[->] (0, 0) -- (1, 0) node[anchor=west] {x};
        \draw[->] (0, 0) -- (0, 1) node[anchor=west] {z};
    \end{scope}
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

This way the arcs are parallel as suggested however, I did not find a way to use the coordinates in a nice way for this. Using `node[midway, fill=white] {$\alpha$}` puts the node at the bottom of the arc.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I ill be easy to show, what to do, if you would provide  an example document with showed image ... try `node[midway, fill=white] {$\alpha$};` aruc are paralel, if they have the same center and only different radius.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I added the piece of latex code in the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, your code snipped is not compilable (file `clarky` is unknown), so MWE below contain only part, which draw your angles. For this is used TikZ library `angles` and `quotes` (for details see TikZ & PGF manual, section *41 Angle Library*, page 570--571 and section *18.2.1 The Quotes Syntax*, page 267--268)):

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3.141592]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,
                calc,
                quotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5)% Syntax: [draw options] (center) (initial angle:final angle:radius)
    { \draw[#1] ($(#2)+({#5*cos(#3)},{#5*sin(#3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5); }
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5,
my angle/.style = {draw, <->,
                   angle radius = #1,
                   angle eccentricity=1,
                   anchor=center,
                   },
every pic quotes/.style = {inner sep=1pt, fill=white}
                    ]

    \coordinate (A) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (B) at (0, .7);
    \coordinate (C) at (2, 0);
    \coordinate (E) at ($0.6*(A)+.4*(B)$);
%
    \draw[thick]    (A) -- (C) -- (B);
    \draw[dashed]   (E) -- (C);
\pic [my angle=88mm, "$\alpha$"]     {angle = B--C--A};
\pic [my angle=77mm, "$\alpha_{\text{eff}}$"]   {angle = E--C--A};
\pic [my angle=77mm, "$\alpha_i$"]   {angle = B--C--E};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Sorry about not including Clarky.tex, but yeah it was not really the point of the question

Comment: One issue however, the code seems to work in a standalone documentclass, but my own custom documentclass I'm getting
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \mitalpha 
l.100 ...e=77mm, "$\alpha_i$"]   {angle = B--C--E}
                                                  ;
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: @Nick, code in my answer work with any version of the (recent) document class. Used is `tikz` version 3.1.7 (however, available is from december 27, version 3.1.8). Since you not provide MWE but only code fragment, I'm not able to test answer with document class, which you use. Please, check, if your LaTeX installation is up to date.

Comment: My version is up to date, the problem is that my documentclass somehow clashes with \pic in tikz. The workaround is using the standalone package with arguments mode=buildnew and \includestandalone, which works!